# Kotlin - Testing lambda using mockito

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito

I am using lambda expression in my function, where i need to test my method using mockito.

```
class A {
    fun testLambda(){
      val obj = B()
      obj.testMethod(1,{
        number -> println(number)
        })
    }
}

class B {
    fun testMethod(number : Int,action : (Int) -> Unit){
        action(number+1)
    }
}
```

I need to test these using mockito, i have no idea about this, any help ?

Comment: You want to test if `action` is called with `number + 1`?